# Check Internet Explorer minimal version on Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project

I have created a Setup Project on Visual Studio. I would like that the installer check the version of Internet Explorer that is installed on the target PC and if it is greater version than 8, then aloud to install the product. To achieve it I have created a Registry Launch Condition that checks the registry value of 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`
and then check the value of Version:

[image]

Then in my condition:

[image]

When I build the installers it always says that **It is necessary to install IE 8 or greater**, so this is not working properly because I have installed a greater version. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if it works if you take the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE out of your RegKey. HKLM is already specified in the Root setting.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW, it works fine now, I removed HKLM from the RegKey.